# JQuery-If divs inside form have class show, else hide

Tags: jquery, forms, if-statement

I'm trying to show only the divs that have a specific class and hide the ones that don't. In this example I'm trying to show the divs where class is "panel_profile" and hide the "wood" div. Why is it not working?

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div class="panel_profile"> 
Name: <input>Data</input>
</div>

<div class="panel_profile"> 
Name: <input>Data</input>
</div>

<div class="wood">  
Name: <input>Data</input>
</div>
</form>
```

**JQuery** (I even tried replacing the PHP variable with the correct class to test but it did not work)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $("div").hasClass("<?php echo $tablename; ?>") ) {
    $(".div").show();
} else {
    $(".div").hide();
}
});
```

Comment: if you know ahead of time what the correct class is, consider just making it a css rule.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hide();
    $("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('<?php echo $tablename; ?>'))
           $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A jquery selector returns a collection, however when you run

```
if ( $("div").hasClass("<?php echo $tablename; ?>") ) {
```

you are only checking whether a single div has that class. Instead, you could do:

```
$("div.panel_profile").show();
$("div.wood").hide();
```

which operators directly on the collections.

Comment: _"you are only checking a single div"_ - Not quite - `.hasClass()` checks if at least one element in the collection has the class. But yes, it is still the wrong way to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `if` or the `.hasClass()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // hide all divs
   $("div").hide();
   // then show just the ones with the class
   $("div.<?php echo $tablename; ?>").show();
});
```

`$("div.someclass")` will select all div elements that have the class `"someclass"`. You can combine your php code with this: `$("div.<?php echo $tablename; ?>")`.

Note that you had a dot in your selector for `$(".div").show()` and `$(".div").hide()`, which meant you were looking for elements with the *class* `"div"`, not div elements.

`if ( $("div").hasClass("<?php echo $tablename; ?>") )` wasn't working for your requirement because `.hasClass()` returns `true` if *any* of the elements has the class. To use `.hasClass()` for your purpose you'd need to put it inside a loop.

**UPDATE:** From your comment it sounds like you only want to apply this processing to the divs inside the form. If so, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form").find("div").hide().filter(".<?php echo $tablename; ?>").show();
});
```

I've done it a slightly different way just for variety, to show how jQuery lets you chain methods together. The above says to select the form element (you could do this by id if the form has one, otherwise this will select every form on the page), then within that form [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) all of its divs and hide them, then [.`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) that list of divs to just the ones with the specified class and show them.

Comment: It works, but it also hides unnecessary divs like the one that holds the form.

Comment: Your question says _"I'm trying to show **only the divs that have a specific class** and hide the ones that don't."_ If you meant that this should be applied only to divs that are inside that form you should have said so - I'll update my answer to allow for that possibility.